# Homestead up failing after Mac OSx El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: laravel, osx-elcapitan

Everything was working fine prior to an upgrade to Mac OSx El Cap. Now when I run homestead up to boot my laravel projects, I get this error.

```
> $ homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '0.2.2'. The latest is version '0.3.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Comment: SOLVED IT - After several rabbit holes, I came across a developer's comment that he came across the same issue which required a whole rebuild from the ground up. 1. Update Virtual Box. 2) Update Vagrant. 3) Update Homestead.